# How to extract rows of data from another sheet based lookup of "name", needs to be dynamic.

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting, lookup-tables

OWNER | REGION | PROGRAM | TOTALS | FORECAST | JAN | FEB | ETC

How can I lookup a name in the region column, "Europe" and then if it is true copy the entire row of data onto a new tab/sheet.

All of the regional data is contained in a table titled Table13, so I guess is there a way to reference the table and drill down on region and then copy the entire row of data onto a new sheet? I would like it to be dynamic so any time the table is update, the new sheet is also updated.

LOOKUP in table13, region region column = Europe copy entire row and paste into new tab/worksheet

I would prefer to not use a VBA due to company restrictions but if it is literally the only way I will have to use it.

THANKS FOR ANY AND ALL HELP!!! :)

Comment: Use `Match()` to get the row number then use `Index()` to get the row data. This isn't copy/paste but you would need to use VBA for that.

Comment: would this still be dynamic? if I update TABLE1, would it reflect on the new Europe region tab?

Comment: Or maybe set up a pivottable and some getpivotdata formulas and have region as page field. You would need formulas to cater to the max number of pivot rows and something like IFERROR wrap to hide errors....

Comment: pivot table doesn't really solve the problem, not trying to view the data in that manner. I want to be able to work on the new sheet without it affecting the OG sheet but want the OG sheet to populate dynamic inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Power Query** it is an add-in for Excel 2010+ versions. You can download it and activate easily. There you can connect any data source and in the Query Editor, you can filter the field `[Region]` by `"Europe"`, even you can unpivot the `[Dates]` fields for future analysis, and then it will create a table in a new sheet with your selected data.

[image]

Comment: my company does not allow any outside addins. everything has to be done in excel 2010 unfortunately

Comment: But Power Query is developed by Microsoft also it comes by default in Excel 2016 (Get & Transform)  [Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379)

Comment: I understand that, I have excel 2010 and cannot use ANY addins.